# Call to undefined method Mail::setMessageType()

Tags: php

I have a website and it has a member registry ([Way of Life](http://w-o-l.ml/register.php)). It uses phpmailer which I am not very familiar with. When you enter data and click register, it returns this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mail::setMessageType() in
>   /home/u536535282/public_html/classes/phpmailer/phpmailer.php on line
>   989

The lines that this is referring to are shown below:

```
$this->error_count = 0; // reset errors
$this->setMessageType();
   if (!$this->AllowEmpty and empty($this->Body)) {
       throw new phpmailerException($this->lang('empty_message'), self::STOP_CRITICAL);
   }
```

If someone colud tell me what i need to change, I would appreciate it, as it would get my site going again

Comment: You could try using `print_r( get_class_methods('phpmailer') );` to show what methods that class does have - it might be a simple typo?

Comment: it does not seem so...

Comment: ? it doesn't seem so what? That you cannot use `get_class_methods` or that the method does not exist? Just found this link - might be useful: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=methods

Comment: that it was a typo. ill check the link